# Canceling a UILongPressGesture

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm having trouble canceling a UILongPressGesture. The gesture is connected to a button, and when the button is pressed, an avaudiorecorder starts recording audio. I want the audio recording to stop when I move off of the button. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
@IBAction func recordAudio(sender: AnyObject)
{
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended
    {
        session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        recorder.stop()
        recordButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        save()
    }
    else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
    {
        session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, error: nil)
        recorder.record()
        recordButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }
    else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Cancelled
    {
        recorder.stop()
        recordButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

**EDIT - Take 2**

```
@IBAction func recordAudio(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    switch (sender.state)
    {
        case .Ended:
            session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
            recorder.stop()
            recordButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            save()
        case .Began:
            session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, error: nil)
            recorder.record()
            recordButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        case .Cancelled, .Ended:
            recorder.stop()
            recordButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        default:
            break
    }   
}
```

**EDIT - Take 3 (almost there)**

```
@IBAction func recordAudio(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    switch (sender.state)
    {
        case .Ended:
            session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
            recorder.stop()
            recordButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            post()
        case .Began:
            session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, error: nil)
            recorder.record()
            recordButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        case .Cancelled:
            recorder.stop()
            recordButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        case .Changed:
            let touchLocation = recordGesture.locationInView(recordButton)
            if (!CGRectContainsPoint(recordButton.bounds, touchLocation))
            {
                // touch is outside of button
                recorder.stop()
                recordButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                break
            }
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

This code works, the only issue is that .Ended is still being called after the gesture has changed and I release my finger from the screen.

Comment: You could try add an action to the button for `UIControlEventTouchDragOutside`. Are you sure you coudn't get all this functionality from a UIButton, I'm not sure you need the gesture.

Comment: The button won't receive the action because the tap recognizer has consumed the touch already.

Comment: so is the solution removing the longpressgesture altogether?

Comment: you need to remove the _long pressure gesture recogniser_ (this concept is wrong entirely here) and you need to rework the concept with _touch down_, _touch up inside_ and _touch up outside_ gestures instead.

Comment: @holex do you have a code example I can look at?

Answer (score 2):

When the touch of a long press gesture recognizer moves then the function is called with the state `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`.

I would change your code like this...

```
@IBAction func recordAudio(sender: AnyObject)
{
    switch (sender.state) {
        case .Ended:
            session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
            recorder.stop()
            recordButton.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
            save()
        case .Began:
            session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, error: nil)
            recorder.record()
            recordButton.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
        case .Cancelled:
            recorder.stop()
            recordButton.backgroundColor = .redColor()
        case .Changed:
            // detect if the touch has gone outside of the button and stop the recording
        default:
            // do nothing
    }
}
```

**For detecting if the touch is inside the button**

You can do something like this..

```
let touchLocation = recognizer.location(in: recordButton)

if !recordButton.bounds.contains(touchLocation) {
// touch is outside of button
}
```

Not tested or anything. Just typed freehand in Safari.

Comment: I'm getting an error that states: "could not find an overload for "state" that accepts the supplied arguments"... I believe it has something to do with sender being declared AnyObject?

Comment: I changed sender to a UILongPressGestureRecognizer, and added a default case, but unfortunately it didn't cancel when I moved off of the button :/

Comment: Can you edit your question to show you're code. You need to actually detect that it has moved away from the button manually.

Comment: I edited the code above. I just realized I removed the .Changed case, however when I add it I get the error that "case label in a switch should have at least one executable statement"

Comment: Yeah, you're not actually telling it to stop anywhere. Keep the default bit for "do nothing" but add back the .Changed bit. Like I said though. You need to work out where the touch is and then work out if it's outside the button and then you need to stop the recording. You need to detect it all manually.

Comment: @user3353890 Also, you have `.Ended` in the first and the third case.

Comment: @user3353890 I've edited to show what you need. You just need to code the `.Changed` case.

Comment: ah ok, that makes sense about the manual detection. I can look into it more on my own, but would you suggest focusing on the button's location on screen?

Comment: thanks for your help so far. I got the .Changed method to work, my only issue is that .Ended is still being called after I release my finger from the screen even though there is a break. How do I keep .Ended from being called? I don't want the save() method to be executed.

Comment: @user3353890 Maybe you don't actually need the .Changed section. Was thinking about it. Would you want it to stop recording as soon as the touch leaves the button? What if they move out of the button and then back in? I think... Get rid of the `.Changed` case and in the `.Ended` case check if the touch is inside the button. If it is inside the button then save otherwise don't save.