# How to add an images in Scrollview in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

i am newbie in iOS Development i want to add a image array in to UIScrollView when i write a code for that then it display only last image of array in to UIScrollview.i not understand what is problem please give me Solution

I write a code for that

```
 for(int index=0; index < [self.imagesa count]; index++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *image=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
    self.zoomImage.bounds=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width +10.0f, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.height);
    self.zoomImage.frame=CGRectMake(index * self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width, 0, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.height);
    [self.zoomImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.zoomImage setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [self.zoomImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    [self.zoomImage setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    [self.objectarray insertObject:self.zoomImage atIndex:index];
    CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width*[self.objectarray count], self.zoomScroll.frame.size.height);
    [self.zoomScroll setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
    [self.zoomScroll addSubview:self.zoomImage];
    [self.zoomScroll addSubview:[self.objectarray objectAtIndex:index]];
}
```

and when i make a local imageview then it was display for that code is [this link shows my old code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858183/how-to-add-an-image-array-in-to-uiscrollview)
it is working but when i write a code for this it Display only Last array image please give me Solution for that. i know this question asked many times but i not get solution.

Comment: zoomImage is your ScrollView?if so what is the value of index?

Comment: bro i edit my code and here zoomImage is my ImageView and ZoomScroll is my Scrollview i want to add zoomimage into ZoomScroll.

Comment: Instead of using scrollview you use "TableView" and add image to each cell by declaring a array of images. You are doing it in difficult way and the result will be same for both.

Comment: where do you allocate the zoomImage(uiimageView)?

Comment: i allocate zoomimage in my .h file like as @property(retain,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *zoomImage;
and Scrollview also like as
@property(retain,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIScrollView *zoomScroll;

Comment: so u have a single imageView in a scrollView and your are changing the frame of tat imageview each time.so it will only show the last image

Comment: then how i write a code for that? then show all image of my array?

Comment: are you kidding? you are using only _one (1)_ `UIImageView` instance, which you are overriding in your loop... you are not simply newbie to iOS, you are newbie to application development and OOP entirely.

Comment: then #holex give me solution please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create new imageView.  `for(int index=0; index < [self.imagesa count]; index++)
{UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init……]}`instead of always using `self.zoomImage`

Comment: #mengxiangjian it is wrking but i want to zoom that imageview when my zoom button was presed then it size was not extended so i make imageview in my .h file please if you have any solution for extended size of my imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
    for(int index=0; index < [self.imagesa count]; index++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];
        NSString *image=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
        UIImageView img=[[UIImageView alloc] init]; // allocate new object
        img.bounds=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width +10.0f, img.frame.size.height);
        img.frame=CGRectMake(index * self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width, 0, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width, self.zoomScroll.frame.size.height);
        [img setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [img setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
        [img sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
        [img setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
        [self.objectarray insertObject:img atIndex:index];
        [self.zoomScroll addSubview:img];
    }
    CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(self.zoomScroll.frame.size.width*[self.objectarray count], self.zoomScroll.frame.size.height);
    [self.zoomScroll setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
```

Comment: #Rijo Joseph it is working i know but i want to extended my imageview Size when zoombutton was pressed then how i extended size of my imageview? i extended my scrollview size but the imageview size is not extended.

Comment: by extend size what exactly you are trying to do?? You want to zoom images inside this scrollview individually?

Comment: #Rijo Joseph i want individually zoom my ScrollView with image when zoom button was pressed i write code for that like as
self.zoomScroll.frame=CGRectMake(10, 40, 300, 400); then Scrollview size was extended but imageview remainning same.when i use your code.

Comment: when you click on zoom, does it open a new view with this image so that the user can pinch zoom?

Comment: #Rijo Joseph no i not want to Open a new view because my app already contain many xib and i want them into a single view to show zoom result.and i not open when zoom is pressed i show the zoomed scrollview in my current view.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861520/canceling-a-uilongpressgesture#26861520 and in - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView method return the current imageview image from ur object array.. I am not sure whether this will work

Comment: what this link bro? i not understand.

Comment: sorry wrong link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877807/pinch-to-zoom-effect-on-uiimageview-inside-scrollview try this